# Heroku not compatible with rest parameter ...args

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Heroku says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

How can I adjust this function to be compatible with heroku?

```
authenticate(...args) {
            var authRequest = {};
            authRequest[Eureca.Protocol.authReq] = args;
            this.socket.send(this.serialize(authRequest));
        }
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979390/how-to-run-node-js-app-with-es2017-features-enabled-on-heroku) helps?

Comment: yes   "node": ">= 7.6.0"

Answer (score 1):

I am not really that familiar with Heroku but you can always do the following. `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` will achieve the same effect as using rest operator in this case.

```
authenticate() {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var authRequest = {};
  authRequest[Eureca.Protocol.authReq] = args;
  this.socket.send(this.serialize(authRequest));
}
```

See the example.

```js
function foo1(...args) {
  console.log(args);
}

function foo2() {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log(args);
}

foo1(1, 2, 3, 4);
foo2(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

And this code is obtained by running `foo1` function through babel transpiler.

```
function foo1() {
  for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
    args[_key] = arguments[_key];
  }

  console.log(args);
}
```